A question about Weitzenbock formula for one form
I am reading a thesis “The magic of Weitzenbock formula”， In Section 3 it gives an expression as shown in the figure
Expression of formula
it gives a  Weitzenbock formula for one form
$$\frac{1}{4}d{{d}^{*}}+{{d}^{*}}d=\delta {{\delta }^{*}}+r$$
But the formula has been given in the previous sections, and it is the usual Weitzenbock formula for one form
$$\frac{1}{2}{{d}^{*}}d+d{{d}^{*}}={{D}^{*}}D+r$$
What I want to ask is what is the difference between these two formulas?
In the thesis he said:
An infinitesimal isometry X, a so-called Killing field, is a solution of the system ${{L}_{X}}g=0$, which, when expressed in terms of covariant derivatives, becomes $\varsigma (DX)=0$ where $\varsigma $ denotes the operation of symmetrization of a linear map. The first-order operator having precisely the map $\frac{1}{2}\varsigma$ as principal symbol is traditionally denoted by ${{\delta }^{*}}$, so that the equation for a Killing field X is ${{\delta }^{*}}X=0$.
My understanding is that $\varsigma (DX)=0$ is $g({{\nabla }_{Z}}X,W)+g({{\nabla }_{W}}X,Z)=0.$ But I don’t understand what is the specific form of ${{\delta }^{*}}$, and how does the operator defined by the killing field operate on the one form?

Please write the formula in LaTeX, instead of as a link to an image. You are asking about the definitions of the notation used. Are these not stated in the thesis itself?

@Deane I know weitzenbock formula for one form, but I don't understand why it has other representations. The reason why I send the picture is to include the upper and lower paragraphs of the formula, as well as the origin and application of the formula. In fact, there is another formula at the end of this paper.

I can calculate that by comparing the formulas ${{\left( \delta {{\delta }^{*}}X \right)}{i}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits{j}{({{X}{j,ij}}+{{X}{i,jj}}-{{X}_{j,ji}})}$
How to get the specific expression of $\delta$ based on this formula
